# Ember-Data FixtureAdapter - commiting new record to HasMany association causes entries in array to dissapear

Tags: ember.js

I'm having a problem with the FixtureAdapter in ember-data where I add a new record to a HasMany array but when I attempt to commit this to the store, all of the entries in the association disappear.

This doesn't seem to happen with the RESTAdapter but I was wondering if anyone can shed any light on what is happening here.

I have created a jsfiddle showing the problem. http://jsfiddle.net/ianpetzer/jSRLV/
If you select the *Facilities for Client* link and then create a new Facility and attempt to save.

The methods in the ClientFacilitiesController are responsible for creating and committing the changes.

```
App.ClientsFacilitiesController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  create_proposed_facility: function () {
  var newFacility;
  //I have also tried this alternate code that is commented out
  //newFacility = this.store.createRecord(App.Facility);
  //newFacility.set('client', this.get('model'));
  //return this.get('facilities').pushObject(newFacility);        
  newFacility = this.get('facilities').createRecord();
  newFacility.set('client', this);
},
save: function () {
  this.store.commit();
}
});
```

My question is whether I can alter my code to make this work with the FixtureAdapter or whether this is a bug with the FixtureAdapter.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The FixtureAdapter is actually not committing any changes to yout FIXTURES array.
But there is a PR about that : https://github.com/emberjs/data/pull/728